# C++ Objects in Array owerwritten

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, stack-overflow

I have a class where I generate new objects and store them in a array. Problem is, that the data of the first object is being overwritten with the data of the second as soon as I add a second object.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
    Rotor rot[100]; // How can I make this flexible?

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    for (int i = 1; i < (argc - 1); i++) {
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(argv[i]);
        if (inFile.fail()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Error reading file!");
            return 1;
        }
        rot[i] = Rotor();
        int n;
        while (inFile >> n) {
            rot[i].import(n);
        }
    }
...
```

Class Rotor:

```
#include "Rotor.h"

int inmap[26];
int outmap[26];
int impcount;

Rotor::Rotor() {
    impcount = 0;
}

void Rotor::import(int i) {
    outmap[i] = impcount;
    inmap[impcount] = i;
    impcount++;
}
```

Now rotor[1].outmap[0] is 1 at the beginning, but after I added rotor[2] it changes to the same value as rotor[2].outmap[0] = 2.
Is there also a way to make the Array length flexible so that it only uses as many space as needed? It is required in later methods.

Thanks

Comment: `Rotor rot[100]; // How can I make this flexible?` => `vector<Rotor> rot; rot.resize(N);`

Answer (score 2):

Your `Rotor` class uses static arrays (shared by all isntances) to store its internal data. This is why each subsequent instance of Rotor appears to *overwrite* the first one. This is very bad. And generally you should avoid static (global) data in C++ programs.

```
 int inmap[26];
 int outmap[26];
 int impcount;
```

You need to make those private members of the class instead:

```
 class Rotor{
    private:
        int inmap[26];
        int outmap[26];
        int impcount;
        // other private members here
    public:
        // constructor and other public methods here
 };
```

As far as making the array flexible, you could do it by hand (use an array allocated on the heap, and resize the array when the number of items equals capacity - you could double the capacity each time the current capacity is met by allocating a new array, copying the contents of the old one and deleting the original) or much easier and less error-prone, just use a dynamic array implementation such the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your variables in the global scope.

Please take a look at the cpp scopes:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

As mike said you need to declare them inside the class. I guess that you want to access those arrays directly like: myrotorobject.inmap[0]. Then I would recommend to make them Public and not Private.

Comment: I'd argue against making internal arrays public. It would be better to create accessor methods for manipulating them on the public surface.